# Multiple Unix Sessions

Tags: ssh, tty

Is there any way I can open multiple Unix sessions on different servers at the same time? I don't want to use ssh, as I want to monitor the CPUs of all those servers at the same time, which will keep changing with time.

Comment: Do you mean http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/?  Can you expand on your question?  You want them in multiple terminals?  You want an aggregated single terminal monitoring some set of variables?  It has to update in real-time?

Comment: Define what you mean by *"open multiple Unix session of different servers"* and what it would mean **in contrast to** using SSH.

Answer (score 1):

If not using X11 then `screen` will allow you to multiplex terminals and have multiple `ssh` sessions running.

Comment: Also try `tmux` a terminal multiplexer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of open source monitoring software that you could use to keep statistics of CPU usage.

You can use something "simple" as [collectd](http://collectd.org/) or some enterprise full fledged monitor system as [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/).

In any case, the simplest technology to fetch cpu/load/memory statistics from a set of remote server is [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol).